# jQuery and TinyMCE: textarea value doesn't submit

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) and [TinyMCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE) to submit a form, but there is a problem in serialization in that the Textarea value doesn't post.

Here is the code:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="post.php">
    <textarea name="question_text" id="question_text" style="width:543px;height:250px;"></textarea>
</form>
```

language: lang-js

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#result').html(data);
            $('.loading').hide();
        }
    })
    return false;
});

tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,separator,image,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,jformatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,styleprops,cite,link,unlink,media,advhr,code,preview",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    extended_valid_elements :"a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
});
```

Can you explain to me what I should change, and why, in order to get the value in the text area posted?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64599372/7186739

Answer (score 194):

Before submitting the form, call `tinyMCE.triggerSave();`

Comment: Using TinyMCE 3.2+ with jquery plugin:`$('#textarea_id').tinymce().save();` in the onSubmit handler of your form.

Comment: @Brenden  I am using 3.5.8 version of tinymce and in console it shows error tinymce() is not a function. I have fixed my issue with eldar thing

Comment: Best answer, short but sweet and is also the cleanest solution. Works with multiple fields too. Only drawback is that this triggers saving for *all* elements.

Comment: tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });

Comment: Dan Malcolm has the best answer for the current version - please see post below - need 70 more upvotes to be listed first.

Comment: For anyone who don't know how to use and where to place `triggerSave()`, here is an example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24284657/128761

Comment: short and clean

Answer (score 127):

You can configure TinyMCE as follows to keep the values of hidden textareas in sync as changes are made via TinyMCE editors:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            editor.save();
        });
    }
});
```

The textarea elements will be kept up to date automatically and you won't need any extra steps before serializing forms etc.

This has been tested on TinyMCE 4.0

Demo running at: http://jsfiddle.net/9euk9/49/

Update: The code above has been updated based on DOOManiac's comment

Comment: Great, it works now. I don't understand why something like this isn't mentioned on the editor's documentation.

Comment: `tinemce.triggerSave()` calls the `save()` function for ALL your active editors. If you have more than one, it is more efficient to set your onChange function like so: `editor.on('change', editor.save);`

Comment: @DooManiac - Good call, thanks. Answer and jsfiddle updated. I retained the anonymous function in the callback to ensure that save is called as a method of the editor object.

Comment: There is a bug with tinymce versions above 4.1.0 with the bold and italic buttons for which the 'mce-active' class is not added directly (but only after a few character typed in the textarea field) - thus the buttons don't look activated... wired... (http://jsfiddle.net/9euk9/304/)

Answer (score 29):

From
[TinyMCE, jQuery and Ajax forms](http://maestric.com/doc/javascript/tinymce_jquery_ajax_form):

> ### TinyMCE Form Submission
>
> - When a textarea is replaced by TinyMCE, it's actually hidden and TinyMCE editor (an iframe) is displayed instead.
> - However, it's this textarea's contents which is sent when the form is submitted. Consequently its contents has to be updated before the form submission.
> - For a standard form submission , it's handled by TinyMCE . For an Ajax form submission, you have to do it manually, by calling (before the form is submitted):
>
>   `tinyMCE.triggerSave();`

```
$('form').bind('form-pre-serialize', function(e) {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
});
```

Answer (score 27):

That's because it's not a textarea any longer. It's replaced with an iframe (and whatnot), and the serialize function only gets data from form fields.

Add a hidden field to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="question_html" name="question_html" />
```

Before posting the form, get the data from the editor and put in the hidden field:

```
$('#question_html').val(tinyMCE.get('question_text').getContent());
```

(The editor would of course take care of this itself if you posted the form normally, but as you are scraping the form and sending the data yourself without using the form, the onsubmit event on the form is never triggered.)

Comment: I'm doing this with the jquery ajaxForm plugin and the textarea value doesn't get passed until my 2nd submit, so I 'm thinking you can't change the submitted data in the onsubmit handler.

Comment: @Brenden: If the plugin also uses the onsubmit event to intercept the form, then you have to make sure that your event handler runs first, otherwise the plugin will gather the data from the form before you have a chance to move the data from the editor into a form field.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 23):

When you run ajax on your form, you need to tell TinyMCE to update your textarea first:

```js
// TinyMCE will now save the data into textarea
tinyMCE.triggerSave(); 
// now grap the data
var form_data = form.serialize();
```

Answer (score 8):

I used:

```
var save_and_add = function(){
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    $('.new_multi_text_block_item').submit();
};
```

This is all you need to do.

Answer (score 8):

This will ensure that the content gets save when you lose focus of the textarea

```
 setup: function (editor) {
                editor.on('change', function () {
                    tinymce.triggerSave();
                });
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var text = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
$('#textareaid').remove();
$('<textarea id="textareaid" name="textareaid">'+text+'</textarea>').insertAfter($('[name=someinput]'));
```

Comment: Using tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() was the only thing that I could get working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for a while and `triggerSave()` didn't work, nor did any of the other methods.

So I found a way that worked for me ( I'm adding this here because other people may have already tried triggerSave and etc... ):

```
tinyMCE.init({
   selector: '.tinymce', // This is my <textarea> class
   setup : function(ed) {
                  ed.on('change', function(e) {
                     // This will print out all your content in the tinyMce box
                     console.log('the content '+ed.getContent());
                     // Your text from the tinyMce box will now be passed to your  text area ... 
                     $(".tinymce").text(ed.getContent()); 
                  });
            }
   ... Your other tinyMce settings ...
});
```

When you're submitting your form or whatever all you have to do is grab the data from your selector ( In my case: `.tinymce` ) using `$('.tinymce').text()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply use the jQuery plugin and package for TinyMCE it sorts out these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 1):

@eldar: I had the same issue with 3.6.7 running in 'normal mode'; and neither triggerSave or save() were working.

I changed to the jQuery TinyMCE plugin and without having to do anything else it's working now. I'm assuming somewhere along the line they implemented some kind of auto triggerSave for the jQuery version of TinyMCE.

Comment: Interesting finding. I believe you mean version 3.5.7? I just did some testing with 3.5.7 and 3.5.8, and `tinyMCE.triggerSave()` actually works fine for me in normal mode. But you are correct that there is already some sort of auto save in jquery mode, which contradicts http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:autosave: "This plugin will most likely be extended in the future to provide AJAX auto save support."

Answer (score 0):

I just hide() the tinymce and submit form, the changed value of textarea missing. So I added this:

```
$("textarea[id='id_answer']").change(function(){
    var editor_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var editor = tinymce.get(editor_id);
    editor.setContent($(this).val()).save();
});
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

`tinyMCE.triggerSave();` seems to be the correct answer, as it will sync changes from the iFrame to your textarea.

To add to the other answers though - why do you need this? I had been using tinyMCE for awhile and hadn't encountered issues with form fields not coming through. After some research, it turned out to be their "auto patching" of form element submits, which is on by default - http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:submit_patch

Basically, they redefine `submit` to call `triggerSave` beforehand, but *only if* `submit` hasn't already been redefined by something else:

```
if (!n.submit.nodeType && !n.submit.length) {
    t.formElement = n;
    n._mceOldSubmit = n.submit;
    n.submit = function() {
        // Save all instances
        tinymce.triggerSave();
        t.isNotDirty = 1;

        return t.formElement._mceOldSubmit(t.formElement);
    };
}
```

So, if something else in your code (or another 3rd party library) is messing with `submit`, their "auto patching" won't work and it becomes necessary to call `triggerSave`.

EDIT: And actually in the OP's case, `submit` isn't being called at all. Since it's ajax'd, this is bypassing the "auto patching" described above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

1. You must include tinymce jquery plugin in your page (jquery.tinymce.min.js)
2. One of the simplest and safest ways is to use `getContent` and `setContent` with triggerSave.  Example:

   ```
   tinyMCE.get('editor_id').setContent(tinyMCE.get('editor_id').getContent()+_newdata);
   tinyMCE.triggerSave();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use ajax to submit form content is the following:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: new FormData(this),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#result').html(data);
            $('.loading').hide();
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

This way you can correctly submit all form data including TinyMCE data