# TinyMCE not sending value

Tags: javascript, tinymce, lang

Hi All
It's the first time I've used Tiny Mce and I have a problem. Please Help

The editor works fine in editing but when I click submit nothing is sent from the textarea input

Here is the code:

```
<textarea name='proddesc' class='text_area' id='elm1' /></textarea>
```

I'm using jQuery, this is the code:

```
$('#addprod').submit(function(){
                $("#addprodmsg").hide();
        $.post('addprod.php', $("#addprod").serialize(), 
            function(data){
                    $("#addprodmsg").html(data);
        });
                $("#addprodmsg").show();
                return false;
});
```

The Php Code is:

```
foreach($_POST as $key){echo "<script>alert('$key')</script>";}
```

Everything alerts a value but the textarea is not alerting anything.

Also, when I disabled TinyMce and submit the form everything is ok.

2 - I'm using the rtl direction and I have this photo:

`http://www.image-upload.net/images/mly8a68ufs0mdeky6low.jpg`

Look At Style :(

Thank You

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is necessary to update the textareas content with the content of the editors iframe (tinymce uses an editable iframe like most rtes). In order to achieve this you need to call `tinymce.get('elm1').save();` before you submit.

You can also grab the editors content using `tinymce.get('elm1').getContent();` and sent this.t

Comment: I am calling `tinyMCE.triggerSave()` to do this, worth a shot as well.

Comment: this will work as well, triggerSave triggers the save function on all editor instances

Answer (score 8):

```
function SubmitForm() {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    $('#submit-form-training-materials').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Why TinyMCE is not sending updated value?**
Tinymce will not update the html/content of hidden textarea input field when you are using ajax to submit a form. You need to update the content/html of textarea input field manually before submit a form using `tinyMCE.triggerSave()`. Note: textarea will be hidden when you will use it as Tinymce.

**How TinyMCE will send updated value?**
Now we will push the content/html of TinyMCE to textarea.

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        tinyMCE.triggerSave(); //this line of code will use to update textarea content
        
        //your ajax function/code
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure when but TinyMCE is already send updated value to textarea automatically.

I'm testing with version 5.8.2 and it's working fine. Here is example link https://jsfiddle.net/5qou7gap/