# Tiny_mce breaking the form action in a :has_many nested model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I have an article controller that deals with articles. 
I have a comment model that belongs_to: article and my article model :has_many comments.
I have initialized tinymce in my articles controller with

```
uses_tiny_mce :options => {
    :theme => 'advanced', :theme_advanced_resizing => false, :theme_advanced_resize_horizontal => false,
    :theme_advanced_toolbar_location => "top", #:plugins => "preview",
    :theme_advanced_buttons1 => "",
    :theme_advanced_buttons1_add => "", :theme_advanced_buttons2 => "", :content_css => "/stylesheets/style_mce.css",
    :theme_advanced_buttons3 => ""}, :only => [:show, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

I know the buttons are empty, I am just debugging for now. So tiny mce works fine in my article new and edit views where the tiny_mce textarea is for the article model. In my article show view I have a form for my comments that works perfectly without the body being mceEditor. When I add it, the form does nothing. I click on submit and it does nothing at all.

```
<%= simple_form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
  <%= f.input :body, :label => false, :placeholder => "Comment away", :input_html => { :class => "mceEditor" } %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I remove the :class => "mceEditor" it works. When i put it back, the form does nothing when i click on it. The tiny_mce stuff is displayed in the text area but it breaks the form action with no errors. I read over the docs for the tiny_mce gem and it said to put the include for the tiny_mce into the controller that has the action, which is articles, but the model the form in my articles#show view is for comments, so i think the error is something to do with that. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in rails EVER.

<%= f.submit :onclick => "jQuery(tinyMCE.triggerSave())" %>

Tada!

Answer (score 0):

This question/answer might help you: [TinyMCE not sending value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807156/tinymce-not-sending-value/5807432#5807432)

If not - let me know.

Comment: So, to apply this to ruby code, would I need to write javascript to call tinymce.get('whateverclass').save(); when the form is submitted? That seems pretty hack-y and also, tinymce already works for another one of my views...

Comment: ...before the form gets submitted