# TinyMCE textarea and post form using ajax

Tags: ajax, tinymce, save

I m using tinyMCE for textareas and POSTing form through AJAX.

But when I m trying to save textarea value, it is taking old values on first click, but it takes updated values on second click.

I have tried using `tinyMCE.triggerSave()` but it didn't work.

I have also tried `tinyMCE.get('myid').getContent()`, still it takes old values.

My code is as follows.

```
    $(".submit").live("click", function () {
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
            var f = $(this).parents("form");
            var action = f.attr("action");
            var serializedForm = f.serialize();
            //tinyMCE.triggerSave(); also tried putting here
            $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: action,
                 data: serializedForm,
                 async: false,
                 success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                     $(".divform").html(data);
                 },
                 error: function (req, status, error) {
                     alert&("Error occurred!");
                 }
            });
    return false;
    });
```

Please help, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Working Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64599372/7186739

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this instead of `tinymce.triggerSave();`

```
$('#' + 'your_editor_id').html( tinymce.get('your_editor_id').getContent() );
```

Comment: Thanks but i used tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() and it worked.
Thanks for ur reply.

Comment: of course it does: tinyMCE.activeEditor is the same editor instance you get using tinymce.activeEditor . But be aware that tinymce.activeEditor only gets set when the user clicks into the editor else it's undefined while tinymce.get('your_editor_id') will always give you an editor instance

Comment: It took me weeks to figure this out. triggerSave() appears to fail in Firefox for some reason that I never figured out.

Comment: @BenPower Do you have a reference to someone else having a FF-only triggerSave() issue? I can't find anyone else having a similar problem.

Comment: Awesome stuff dude, very helpful

Answer (score 54):

You can configure TinyMCE as follows to keep the values of hidden textareas in sync as changes are made via TinyMCE editors:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    }
});
```

With this in place, you can access up-to-date values directly from the textarea elements at any time.

This has been tested on TinyMCE 4.0

Demo running at: http://jsfiddle.net/9euk9/

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me on TinyMCE 3.x

Comment: @Pere - I've posted an alternative answer that works on TinyMCE 3.x

Comment: Worth noting that adding the `editor.triggerSave()` on `init` as well can be useful for inline editors as the corresponding hidden fields will not have a value on load

Answer (score 6):

An alternative implementation to the one posted by Dan Malcolm, for TinyMCE 3.x, would be as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.onChange.add(function() {
            editor.save();
        });
    }
});
```

As well as working on 3.x, this version uses `editor.save` instead of `tinymce.triggerSave`, which means it only updates the current editor rather than all editors in the page.

Comment: you are my hero man, keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2):

user this script before posting data by using Ajax. This is javascript code before use please load tiny mce js file and user it.

**tinymce.triggerSave();**

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'post', 
    url: 'autoSaveReport.php', 
    data: $('form').serialize(), 
    success: function (result) { 
        var redirectURL = window.location.pathname; 
        var redirectURL1 = redirectURL+"?incid="+result; 
        window.location = window.location+"?incid="+result; 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For me works fine with

`tinymce.triggerSave();`

Put it before the ajax post

Answer (score 0):

I know time passed but i found this solution today.

Before serialize the form you must save the editor just using the method:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.save();
var serializedForm = f.serialize();
```

Maybe this helps some comrade.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple instances:

```
tinymce.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas"
    ,body_class: 'tinymceclass'
    ,setup: function (editor) {
        editor.onChange.add(function() {
            $('#' + this.id).html( tinymce.get(this.id).getContent() );
        });
    }
});
```