# MVC5 how to bind TinyMCE value to model

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I tried to bind TinyMCE into my model, but it always return null on postback. My Code:

View :

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(Function(m) m.LangValue)

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tinymce.init({selector: 'textarea'});
    })
</script>
```

Model :

```
<Required(ErrorMessage:="Required")> _
<Display(Name:="LangValue")> _
<StringLength(8000, ErrorMessage:="Maximum 8000 characters")> _
<AllowHtml()> _
Public Property LangValue As String
    Get
        Return _langValue
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _langValue = value
    End Set
End Property
```

It is working fine if I remove the tinymce script so I checked the HTML and it seems TinyMCE hide the textarea with display: none and replace it with their own UI. Is it possible to replace the textarea value with TinyMCE editor value on postback?

Any help will be appreciated. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Am i understand right that you create TinyMCE in dialog? I mean you create DOM.

Comment: no I'm not, just a normal html view page with razor syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed it by moving the script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        tinymce.init({selector: 'textarea'});
    })
```

from inside EditorTemplates to my Layout.

I don't know why it doesn't work if I put it inside EditorTemplates because my Layout doesn't have anything after @RenderBody, maybe someone could enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force TinyMCE to populate hidden field you can use this funtion before submit:

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, does this mean I have to call triggerSave everytime I need to get the value from the editor? Is it possible to auto call triggerSave on postback? I did a few quickcheck and it seems triggersave is tinyMCE 3.x API, I'm currently using tinyMCE 4.x

Comment: Actually, if i remember right tinyMCE should populate it on Submit by delault if there are no some tricky things. 

And yes it means you should do it every time... 

I think it should work with tinyMCE 4.0, as it works in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24284657/1849444) with a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9euk9/).

Comment: As you can see, you can use `change` event to populate values.

Comment: I just made a dummy solution with dummy model and view, it works. TinyMCE is able to return the value on postback. But it is still not working in my main solution, is it possible this happened because I put TinyMCE inside EditorFor?

Comment: I can't say you exactly why it happends. In my project i had to use `tinyMCE.triggerSave();`

Comment: So, I fixed it by moving the script

    $(document).ready(function () {
            tinymce.init({selector: 'textarea'});
        })

from inside EditorTemplates to my Layout.

I don't know why it doesn't work if I put it inside EditorTemplates because my Layout doesn't have anything after @RenderBody, maybe someone could enlighten me.