# Tinymce plugin not getting textarea value to upload in database

Tags: php

I am trying to upload data in database.

I using `tinymce` plugin to textarea editor. When I submit my data, textarea value uploads empty text. Please find below the frontend and backend code.

Frontend Code:

```
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<textarea class="tinymce" name="product_tip" id="product_tip" placeholder="" col="5"></textarea>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" class="upload-btn"/>
</form>
```

Backend Code:

```
<?php
    $product_tip=$_POST["product_tip"];
    if(empty($product_tip)) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please enter Product tips.</div>";
    }
    else{
        $result=mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO product(tip) VALUES ('$product_tip')")or die("Could not retrieve image: " .mysqli_error($conn));
        echo 1;
    }
?>
```

and this my connection code for frontend and backend file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
    $('.upload-btn').click(function(){

        var formdata=new FormData($('#upload')[0]);
        $.ajax({
                url:'includes/backend_product_upload.php',
                method: "POST",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data : formdata,
            success:function(answer_from_actionpage){
                if(answer_from_actionpage == 1){
                    $('.error').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>Successfully Product Upload</div>");
                    //$('.form-control').val("");
                }else{
                    $('.error').html(answer_from_actionpage);
                }
            }
        })
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TinyMCE textarea and post form using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393512/tinymce-textarea-and-post-form-using-ajax)

Comment: Your SQL query is _wide open_ to SQL Injections. Use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries like that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have `async` set to false?

Answer (score 0):

Add `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` in connection file like this-

```
$('.upload-btn').click(function(){
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    var formdata=new FormData($('#upload')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url:'includes/backend_product_upload.php',
        method: "POST",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data : formdata,
        success:function(answer_from_actionpage){
            if(answer_from_actionpage == 1){
                $('.error').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>Successfully Product Upload</div>");
                //$('.form-control').val("");
            }else{
                $('.error').html(answer_from_actionpage);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, TinyMCE will automatically update the underlying `<textarea>` when the form is submitted via standard HTML form submission.  This is built-in behavior in TinyMCE as the overhead of keeping the `<textarea>` constantly in sync is not needed for most applications.

If you are not relying on a standard HTML form submission event you have a couple of options...

**When you start the AJAX form submission process:**

TinyMCE has a `triggerSave()` method that forces the editor to sync with the `<textarea>` immediately.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#triggersave

You can call the `triggerSave()` first thing when your user wants to submit the form and then perform your validation.

**TinyMCE Events:**

As your response to your own question shows you can certainly rely on various editor events to sync the editor to the `<textarea>` via the `triggerSave()` method.  There is no technical issue  with this just know that you will likely trigger a large number of these events if you rely on something like the change event.  If you have large/complex HTML content or many editors on one page constantly syncing with the underlying `<textarea>` may impact the browser's performance.

**Which is better?**

*If you DON'T need real time validation of the content...* just calling `triggerSave()` at the start of the AJAX submission process is probably easier (no TinyMCE configuration code tied to an event needed) and creates less overhead for the browser.

*If you DO need real time validation of the content...* using an event like the change event to sync the `<textarea>` is the better solution.  It might look like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#myTextarea",
  ...
  setup: function (editor) {
      editor.on('change', function () {
          tinymce.triggerSave();
      });
  }
});
```