# Tinymce doesn't save or submit my content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tinymce

I'm not a professional programmer, I've had little experience working with Javascript and so this Tinymce is confusing me. Basically my client wants to update the content himself without touching the code, so I have to set up this Tinymce so he can edit the content directly on browser. I've followed the instruction to install Tinymce but when I click submit, nothing happens. When I click save, it links me to the PHP page with its code.  Below are all my codes. Please tell me what I need to do.

In the HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script>
  tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#elm1",
        theme: "modern",
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        plugins: [
             "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
             "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
             "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
       ],
       content_css: "css/content.css",
       toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons", 
       style_formats: [
            {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
            {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
            {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
            {title: 'Table styles'},
            {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
        ],

         setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    }
    }); 

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

  var url = "news.php";

  $("#SubmitBtn").click(function(){
    //"content" will PHP variable 
    $.post(url, { "page_content" : tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() }, function(respond){

       if ( respond == ){
          alert('Content saved to file');
          return;
       } else {
          //Error message assumed
          alert(respond);
        }
    });
  });

});

</script>
```

The form:

```
<form method="post" action="news.php">
 <textarea id="elm1" name="page_content">The content I wanna edit</textarea>
        <input type="button" id="SubmitBtn" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

In the PHP page:

```
<?php

if ( isset($_POST['page_content']) ){

   //This is what you want - HTML content from tinyMCE
   //just treat this a string

   if ( save_html_to_file($_POST['page_content'], 'news.html') ){
     //Print 1 and exit script
     die(1);
   } else {
      die('Couldnt write to stream');
   }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param string $content HTML content from TinyMCE editor
 * @param string $path File you want to write into
 * @return boolean TRUE on success
 */
function save_html_to_file($content, $path){
   return (bool) file_put_contents($path, $content);
}
```

Comment: Most likely need to stop the form from submitting...`$("#SubmitBtn").click(function(){` needs to be something like `$("#SubmitBtn").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault() });`

Comment: Hmm it still does nothing when i click submit.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64599372/7186739

Answer (score 2):

try add this code to the submit button

```
onclick="tinyMCE.triggerSave(true,true);"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `e.preventDefault();` to stop the form from submiting

```
  $("#SubmitBtn").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
        //"content" will PHP variable 
        $.post(url, { "page_content" : tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() }, function(respond){

           if ( respond == ){
              alert('Content saved to file');
              return;
           } else {
              //Error message assumed
              alert(respond);
            }
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may solve your problem just get the content of editor by `ed.getContent()`

```
 $("#SubmitBtn").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var ed = tinyMCE.get('page_content');
     var data = ed.getContent() // get data of editor
     $.post(url, { "page_content" : data }, function(respond){

           if ( respond == ){
              alert('Content saved to file');
              return;
           } else {
              //Error message assumed
              alert(respond);
            }
        });
      });
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesnt work, the submit button seems to do nothing. I'm wondering what's wrong..

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle with your code in your question so that I can see what is happening with your code.