# Can't get value from tinyMCE editor

Tags: forms, jsf, xhtml, tinymce

I am using JSF 2.1. I'm trying to use TinyEditor on a . Here is my code of xhtml file-

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="editor_style.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="dropdown_menu/dropdown.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css/main.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css/dropdown.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css/drop-down.css" />

    <h:outputScript name="dropdown_menu/stuHover.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="js/my_js.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.min.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="js/tinyeditor.js"></h:outputScript>

</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div class="content">
        <ui:include src="/template/layout/commonLayout.xhtml" />
        <ui:include src="/template/layout/menu.xhtml" />
        <h:form id="form">
            <div class="quick_links">
                <div class="q_title"></div>
                <div class="q_window">
                    <div class="q_top"></div>
                    <div class="q_main">

                        <h:inputTextarea id="input" value="#{EditorBean.value}"
                            style="width:100%; height:300px;">Sample FAQ</h:inputTextarea>

                        <h:outputScript>                        
                new TINY.editor.edit('editor',{
                    id:'form:input',
                    width:945,
                    height:175,
                    cssclass:'te',
                    controlclass:'tecontrol',
                    rowclass:'teheader',
                    dividerclass:'tedivider',
                    controls:['bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','|','subscript','superscript','|',
                              'orderedlist','unorderedlist','|','outdent','indent','|','leftalign',
                              'centeralign','rightalign','blockjustify','|','unformat','|','undo','redo','n',
                              'font','size','style','|','hr','link','unlink'],
                    footer:true,
                    fonts:['Verdana','Arial','Georgia','Trebuchet MS'],
                    xhtml:true,
                    cssfile:'style.css',
                    bodyid:'editor',
                    footerclass:'tefooter',
                    toggle:{text:'Source',activetext:'HTML',cssclass:'toggle'},
                    resize:{cssclass:'resize'}
                });
               </h:outputScript>

                    </div>
                    <div class="q_bottom"></div>
                </div>

                <h:commandButton id="button" value="Savebutton"
                    action="#{EditorBean.test}"></h:commandButton>
            </div>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </h:form>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript">footer();</script>

</h:body>
</html>
```

and my Bean class is

```
package com.denso.rms.beans;

import java.awt.Window;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.resources.windows;

public class EditorBean {     
    private String value; 


    public String getValue() {      
        return value;  
    }  

    public void setValue(String value) {

        this.value = value;         
    }  
    public String test() {
        System.out.println("Value is-" +value);
        return value;
    }       

}
```

Also i did entry in faces-config.xml

Basic problem is if I try print "value" it shows nothing. If i remove Editor then it works fine. So problem is in `<h:inputtextarea>` of editor because when i try to print the same value in getter and setter, its showing nothing.
what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That's because it's not a textarea any longer. It's replaced with an iframe (and whatnot), and the serialize function only gets data from form fields.[Problem jquery and tinymce : textarea value doesn't submit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2122147/617373)

So you have to *extract* its value before posting to server

One approach could be adding the following to the submit `h:commandBttonon`

```
onclick="tinyMCE.triggerSave();"
```

Or

```
onclick="$('#form\\:input').tinymce().save();"
```

If this one wont work than the following solution will (is is better INMO)

Modify your `h:commandButton` like this

```
 <h:commandButton onclick="save_and_add();return false;" id="button" 
     value="Savebutton"></h:commandButton>
```

this is the content of the js function

```
function save_and_add(){
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    $('#form\\:button2').click();
};
```

now add another hidden button that will do the actual submit

```
<h:commandButton id="button2" style="display:none;"
 action="#{EditorBean.test}"></h:commandButton>
```

Comment: @Daniel- Thanks for your valuable reply but basic problem is with <h:inputtextarea> . From editor's text , it should pass value when i write value="#{EditorBean.value}" but it does'nt.so why in commandbutton its not getting value .

Comment: from what I understand you need to call something like `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` in order that the value from tineMCE will get back into the `<h:inputtextarea>`

Comment: also, are you aware of the Pimefaces JSF Component Library and their editor ? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf

Comment: Yes i am aware ,but not allowed to use them.. :(
also solution u gave is not working..
It is displaying both buttons. What should i do?

Comment: had a typo , should be `display:none;`  + updated the `save_and_add` function  also , check your browser console for client side possible errors... and debug the save_and_add function

Comment: In order to see if the input text area value is aupdate use `("#form\\:input").val();` you can use it in alert() or console.log()...

Comment: @Daniel- Its Working Perfectly for me now...Thank you so much!!
definitely deserve upvote.. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20735/discussion-between-kalak-and-daniel)

Comment: The hidden button approach .

Comment: +1 Really helped me. The first solution will work correct, you can just combine this with the `action=#{}`.