# Replacing a textarea with WordPress TinyMCE wp_editor()

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I am trying to replace a textarea with wp_editor()

My textarea form element looks like this:

```
<textarea name="post_text" id="post_text" rows="3"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
```

Then I have:

```
wp_editor( $content, 'post_text' );
```

The problem I am getting is both the form textarea and the wp_editor textarea are outputted on the page. Why are both textareas displaying? I only need one textarea to display. Everything saves fine, I just have this problem of 2 textareas showing.

EDIT: Is it as simple as putting a `display: none;` on my form's textarea so just the wp_editor() textarea displays? That seems to work but feels a bit hackish.

Comment: I solve same issue by remove `<textarea>` tag completely from my page only need for   `$settings =   array  ( 'textarea_name'   =>   'text_name'   ) ;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. You can use a third parameter to pass an array of arguments. Now this is pretty obvious as outlined in the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

What is a little confusing (the source of my problem) is $editor_id may only contain lowercase letters. So if your form processing script is looking for something with underscores in it (as mine was) then you'll need to do this:

```
$settings = array( 'textarea_name' => 'post_text' )

wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

Note you can't do this:

```
wp_editor( $content, 'post_text' );
```

Which is where I went wrong.

Comment: This displays the HTML version of the WP editor, but does not display the tinymce editor.

Comment: In my case I want to add a text field. How to do it? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/318814/how-to-modify-default-taxonomy-field-to-a-single-text-field

Answer (score 2):

If you put a text area in your code

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Then of course it's going to show up on the page, that's what it's supposed to do. Unless there's something I'm misunderstanding, I don't see how that doesn't make sense.

Like you suggested, I think this will do what you want:

```
<textarea style="display:none" name="post_text" id="posttext" rows="3"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
```

It will still be there functionally, but invisible.

Comment: Thanks. So I don't need to have the textarea element on the page? Can I just remove it? Is that how wp_editor() is intended to work?

Comment: Hm. I looked into TinyMCE some more and it appears I misunderstood your question. Could you provide more code? I think the issue is occuring elsewhere.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where the problem is happening elsewhere? That is in fact all the code I have so far. Do you mean the form processing code? That is coming from a plugin called Simple Front End Post https://github.com/sbrajesh/bp-simple-front-end-post

Comment: That's *all* your code? Is the call to `wp_editor` inside `<?php` and `?>` ? What are you using the TinyMCE editor for?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I'm using the TinyMCE editor to edit WordPress posts from the front end. I think I may have resolved the problem. Doing the following lets you remove the form's textarea from the page and use the textarea that is outputted by wp_editor(): $settings = array( 'textarea_name' => 'bp_simple_post_text' ...

Comment: Fabulous :) Remember to post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 2):

The following PHP code turns into a textarea with the name & id "expirationErrorMessage".

```
$id = "expirationErrorMessage";
$name = 'expirationErrorMessage';
$content = esc_textarea( stripslashes( $yourtext ) );
$settings = array('tinymce' => true, 'textarea_name' => $name);
wp_editor($content, $id, $settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of outputting a new textarea to the page (by `wp_editor()`) and hiding the original textarea with `display: none;`, one can do this:

```
add_action('admin_init', '20331501_convert_textarea_to_wysiwyg');

function 20331501_convert_textarea_to_wysiwyg(){
    wp_enqueue_editor();
    add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', function() {
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function(){
                wp.editor.initialize('the-id-of-your-textarea-without-the-#', {
                    setup: function (editor) {
                        editor.on('change', function () {
                            editor.save();
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }, 10, 2 );
}
```

This code snippet converts the *existing* textarea to wysiwyg. The `editor.save()` takes care of updating the textarea value so that it gets passed along when one submits the form. ([credits to @Dan Malcolm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24284938/3963594))

Answer (score 0):

Call your `template page` where you wish to place `tinyMCE`, on that `template page` place a `placeholder` such as `CONTENT_EDITOR` and use php `str_replace` function to add `tinyMCE` to that `template` content:

```
function add_tinymce_to_page(){
    $creatorHTML                    =   file_get_contents(
        'your-template-pafe.php',
        TRUE
    );

    $editorHTML                     = generate_content_with_editor();
    $creatorHTML                    =   str_replace(
        'CONTENT_EDITOR',
        $editorHTML,
        $creatorHTML
    );

    return $creatorHTML;
}

function generate_content_with_editor(){
    ob_start();
    wp_editor( '', 'tinymcecontenteditor' );
    $editor_contents                = ob_get_contents();
    ob_get_clean();
    return $editor_contents;
}
```

I use `php`'s `ob` so `tinyMCE` does not display before full page is rendered.