# angular TinyMCE: textarea value doesn't submit

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am implementing an angular rich text editor, for that I have choosen TinyMCE, To achieve this rich text editor I have written the following code in angular.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fileupload</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <style>
    .tox-statusbar__branding, .tox-notifications-container, .tox .tox-menubar 
  {display: none !important;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.component.html: -**

```
<textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="message" id="message" maxlength="6000" rows="7"
formControlName="mailbody" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.mailbody.errors }"                                 ></textarea>
```

In component when I tried to access the value of the text area with `this.f.mailbody.value` I am not getting the value of text area.

I  have verified in the internet for solving this, I found in [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122085/jquery-and-tinymce-textarea-value-doesnt-submit)

Is there any solution in angular.

Comment: Why don't you use this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-angular

Comment: yeah, it seems good.